# How do you implement monoid interface for this tree in haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monoids

Please excuse the terminology, my mind is still bending.

The tree:

```
data Ftree a = Empty | Leaf a | Branch ( Ftree a ) ( Ftree a )
    deriving ( Show )
```

I have a few questions:

1. If `Ftree` could not be `Empty`, would it no longer be a `Monoid` since there is no identity value.
2. How would you implement `mappend` with this tree? Can you just arbitrarily graft two trees together willy nilly?
3. For binary search trees, would you have to introspect some of the elements in both trees to make sure the result of `mappend` is still a BST?

For the record, some other stuff `Ftree` could do here:

```
instance Functor Ftree where
    fmap g Empty             = Empty
    fmap g ( Leaf a )        = Leaf ( g a )
    fmap g ( Branch tl tr )  = Branch ( fmap g tl ) ( fmap g tr )

instance Monad Ftree where 
    return             = Leaf
    Empty        >>= g = Empty
    Leaf a       >>= g = g a
    Branch lt rt >>= g = Branch ( lt >>= g ) ( rt >>= g )
```

Comment: I don't see how this could be a monoid. `mappend` must be associative,  and if you just do something like `mappend = Branch` then it's definitely not.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are three answers to your question, one captious and one unhelpful and one abstract:

### The captious answer

```
instance Monoid (Ftree a) where
    mempty = Empty
    mappend = Branch
```

This is an instance of the `Monoid` type class, but does not satisfy any of the required properties.

### The unhelpful answer

What Monoid do you want? Just asking for a monoid instance without further information is like asking for a solution without giving the problem. Sometimes there is a natural monoid instance (e.g. for lists) or there is only one (e.g. for `()`, disregarding questions of definedness). I don’t think either is the case here.

<sup>BTW: There would be an interesting monoid instance if your tree would have data at internal nodes that combines two trees recursively...</sup>

### The abstract answer

Since you gave a `Monad (Ftree a)` instance, there is a generic way to get a `Monoid` instance:

```
instance (Monoid a, Monad f) => Monoid (f a) where
    mempty = return mempty
    mappend f g = f >>= (\x -> (mappend x) `fmap` g)
```

Lets check if this is a Monoid. I use `<> = mappend`. We assume that the `Monad` laws hold (I did not check that for your definition). At this point, recall the [Monad laws written in do-notation](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monad_Laws).

Our `mappend`, written in do-Notation, is:

```
mappend f g = do
  x <- f
  y <- g
  return (f <> g)
```

So we can verify the monoid laws now:

*Left identity*

```
mappend mempty g
≡ -- Definition of mappend
do 
  x <- mempty
  y <- g
  return (x <> y)
≡ -- Definition of mempty
do 
  x <- return mempty
  y <- g
  return (x <> y)
≡ -- Monad law
do 
  y <- g
  return (mempty <> y)
≡ -- Underlying monoid laws
do 
  y <- g
  return y
≡ -- Monad law
g
```

*Right identity*

```
mappend f mempty 
≡ -- Definition of mappend
do
  x <- f
  y <- mempty
  return (x <> y)
≡ -- Monad law
do
  x <- f
  return (x <> mempty)
≡ -- Underlying monoid laws
do 
  x <- f
  return x
≡ -- Monad law
f
```

And finally the important *associativity law*

```
mappend f (mappend g h)
≡ -- Definition of mappend
do
  x <- f
  y <- do
    x' <- g
    y' <- h
    return (x' <> y')
  return (x <> y)
≡ -- Monad law
do
  x <- f
  x' <- g
  y' <- h
  y <- return (x' <> y')
  return (x <> y)
≡ -- Monad law
do
  x <- f
  x' <- g
  y' <- h
  return (x <> (x' <> y'))
≡ -- Underlying monoid law
do
  x <- f
  x' <- g
  y' <- h
  return ((x <> x') <> y')
≡ -- Monad law
do
  x <- f
  x' <- g
  z <- return (x <> x')
  y' <- h
  return (z <> y')
≡ -- Monad law
do
  z <- do
    x <- f
    x' <- g
    return (x <> x')
  y' <- h
  return (z <> y')
≡ -- Definition of mappend
mappend (mappend f g) h
```

So for every (proper) Monad (and even for every applicative functor, as Jake McArthur pointed out on #haskell), there is a Monoid instance. It may or may not be the one that you are looking for.

Comment: would it make a difference if the tree was defined as 
'data Tree a = Empty | Leaf a | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a)' ? The reason I am confused is because for 10.2 Instances and Examples found here: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Typeclassopedia#Definition_5, they implemented Foldable for the tree using mappend

Comment: Yes, then I think there is an instance: Just recursively combine the trees, using `mzero` for any value not present in one of the trees.

Comment: wow the extra bit in the general answer section is really helpful thanks a lot!

Comment: The lambda abstraction in the general case for mappend seems to be missing the `->`.

Comment: I'd be tempted to swap the labels of the "unhelpful" and "general" answers, actually.  Also, do you really mean `mzero` everywhere, or should it read `mempty`?

Comment: You are of course right about `mempty`, fixed. And also renamed the “general” answer to “abstract”.